# Why is 'delete(arg)' not throwing any error in the function and giving output as 'myVar'?

Tags: javascript, function

*I was expecting an output as error but instead got output 'my Var'. Can someone please explain why the delete inside the function didn't throw any error.*

```
var a='myVar'
function test(arg){
delete arg;
return arg;
}
test(a);
```

Comment: `delete` will delete *properties of objects*, not variables. It fails silently; it always reports success even if nothing gets deleted. You can even do things like `delete 10` and `delete "Hello, world"` and those will also do nothing, but report success by returning true with no errors.

Comment: delete works on properties of an object, not on a variable. so the call `delete arg` is a no op. delete doesn't raise exceptions for no op

Comment: Add `"use strict"` as the first row of your script to opt in to [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Then you will get "**SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.**".

Answer (score 0):

In [sloppy mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Sloppy_mode) the [delete-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) returns `true` for all cases except when the property is an own non-configurable property, in which case, `false` is returned.

In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) an error is thrown if the property is an own non-configurable property.

The property descriptor have an *configurable* value. If *true* the property may be changed or deleted from the corresponding object.

Variables declared with [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) have the *configurable* set to `false`. (undeclared global variables have it set to `true`)

In your code, `delete` returns `false`, but you don't check it.